# weird django-template-jquery-javascript shenanigans!

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I have the following:

```
return render_to_response('a.html', {'b': 3}, context_instance=...)
```

in `a.html`:

```
{{ b }}
```

outputs 3

```
{% url app.views.something b %}
```

gives me:

```
/something/3/
```

but

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('{{ b }}');
    });
</script>
```

pops up an alert dialog with 3. But if you view the source you get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('0');
    });
</script>
```

If I try to use `{{ b }}` in jquery anywhere else it just keeps returning me '0'.

The same happens if I do the following and check the source before the popup arrives

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("alert('{{ b }}')",2000);
<script>
```

The popup says '3' but the source says '0'.

Has anyone had anything like this before?

**EDIT:**

I have used HTTP fox to deduce that this is an AJAX problem. Django is returning '3' to the browser.

While the example code I have provide above is an over simplification. What I am basically doing is refreshing the div (content_ct's parent) the code is in using a jquery ajax command.

```
$('#ctSelection').change(function() {

    if($('#ctSelection option:selected').val()=='1') {
        $.get('/company/ct/1/', function(data) {
            $('#content_ct').parent().html(data);
        });
    }

    if($('#ctSelection option:selected').val()=='2') {
        $.get('/company/ct/2/', function(data) {
            $('#content_ct').parent().html(data);
        });
    }

});
```

**EDIT**

I believe this is due to jquery overlapping handlers and always using the first one in the stack

Comment: Hi. Are your script tags in a.html? or are they in a separate .js file?

Comment: Hmm. That's very strange. What happens if you do: var b = '{{ b }}'; ?

Comment: I did that and then `alert`'ed the output and the output is '3' but `var b` is '0' in the source

Comment: That's very strange! I don't have an explanation for that. I've created vars for server-side values in exactly the same fashion on lots of projects. I'm not sure what might be causing your templating to behave that way.

Comment: If the alert says 3, then the problem is in the way you are getting your source code. How are you getting it?

Comment: I think it might be a problem with ajax. I've tried a load of different ways of loading the html into a page and its still zero. At the moment I am passing the value into a hidden field when the page loads and then getting the value with jquery when the user changes something. It's an ugly hack, but it works (for now)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't fond a solution for the problem but because django is returning the right code it must be a problem with jquery which I have expanded upon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885163/django-checking-many-to-many-relationship-for-uniqueness).

**EDIT**
I finally switched frameworks to [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) because I couldn't find away round this problem

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo in your javascript closing tag, it should be:

```
</script>
```

instead of

```
<script>
```

Other than that, I tried your javascript with jQuery 1.5 and Django 1.3, it's working fine.