# django checking many-to-many relationship for uniqueness

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many

I have the following `model.py`:

```
class FinancialProduct(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=FP_TABLE_CHOICES)
    businesses = models.ManyToManyField(Business)
```

And the following `forms.py`:

```
class FinancialProductForm(ModelForm):
    business = ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(),required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = FinancialProduct

    def is_unique(self,latestFP):
        if (self.cleaned_data['active'] == latestFP.active and
            self.cleaned_data['name'].capitalize() == latestFP.name and
            self.cleaned_data['acronym'].upper() == latestFP.acronym and
            self.cleaned_data['table_name'] == latestFP.Table_name and
            self.cleaned_data['business'] == latestFP.business):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

The `is_unique()` function is called prior to saving but I am wondering how I can test to see if the many-to-many relationship has changed for `business`. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The form throws up an error as well when submitted due to the business m2m. Does it need additional processing before saving?

Comment: What do you mean by "many-to-many relationship has changed for business"?

Comment: your right. What am I talking about?!? it should be `businesses` (ARRRR!!! typos). If you put it down as an answer I give it a tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`business` should be `businesses` :)